# Method doesn't get called, when calling it from AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, sqlite, jsoup, asynctaskloader, activeandroid

Here's the thing, I have a AsyncTaskLoader loading data from a web page using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) and storing it in SQLite using [ActiveAndroid](http://www.activeandroid.com/).

I have all my parsing and database methods in a class called Parser, I won't bother to explain why, but when I'm calling the Parser.getList method from the Loader,  it doesn't get called.

Absolutely nothing happens, when I moved the content of the method to loadInBackground in my Loader for some reason it worked though. Anyone got an idea on this?

Comment: Please provide a part of problem code

Comment: can you provide your code and/or any related logcat output so we can help better